# Is there a way to put the output of a function into an array in python while using a loop?

Tags: python, arrays

When I cycle through, the issue is that it takes the first value only and does not apply the second and third values. I want this to cycle 20 times to get a better understanding of what's going on. I have looked at W3 schools and other resources and I don't know where I am running into an issue

```
#Creating a loop to run through 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1_0 = Three_Time     #Array 1 initial value
a2_0 = Two_Time     #Array 2 initial value
i = 0
time = [0]
Hour_cap = 20
array1 = np.array([a1_0]* i)
array2 = np.array([a2_0] * i )

while i < Hour_cap:
    i += 1
    time = np.append(time, i)
    array1 = np.append(array1, array1[i]) 
    array2 = np.append(array2, array2[i])

Expected Output: array1[0,192,384....]
```

Comment: It would help us understand what was going on if your code were correctly indented.  It's hard to know what's inside the while loop.

Comment: Please include your import statements as well, so its easier to decode.

Comment: Could you please share output of the script as well as your expected output, to better understand the issue.

Comment: @Spencer You should use empty lists, append to them and only then convert them to numpy arrays. `np.append` is going to take much more time.

Comment: @Spencer I see you've updated your code. Does it work now?

Comment: No it is still not working :(

Comment: @Guimoute How would I do it without using arrays?

Comment: @Spencer You would do `array1.append(array1[i])` instead of `array1 = np.append(array1, array1[i])` in the loop, and `array1 = np.array(array1)` once you exit  the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your loop never started

change `i > Hour_cap` to `i < Hour_cap`